# Get Attribute from object

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, attributes

I want to get a specific `Attribute` on one of an object's properties.

[I used this code as a starter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15609516):

```
public static class ObjectExtensions {
  public static MemberInfo GetMember<T,R>(this T instance, 
    Expression<Func<T, R>> selector) {
      var member = selector.Body as MemberExpression;
      if (member != null) {
        return member.Member;
      }
      return null;
  }

public static T GetAttribute<T>(this MemberInfo meminfo) where T : Attribute {
  return meminfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T)).FirstOrDefault() as T;
  }
}
```

Which you then call like this:

```
var attr = someobject.GetMember(x => x.Height).GetAttribute<FooAttribute>();
```

But I'd like it in one clean step like this:

```
var attr = someobject.GetAttribute<FooAttribute>(x => x.Height);
```

How do I combine those two functions to give this signature?

*Update:* Also, why does this not work for enums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to get that exact signature.  For the method to work, it needs three generic type arguments (one for the object type `T`, one for the attribute type `TAttribute`, and one for the property type `TProperty`).  `T` and `TProperty` can be inferred from usage, but `TAttribute` needs to be specified.  Unfortunately, once you specify one generic type argument, you need to specify all three of them.

```
public static class ObjectExtensions {
    public static TAttribute GetAttribute<T, TAttribute, TProperty> (this T instance, 
        Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> selector) where TAttribute : Attribute {
        var member = selector.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (member != null) {
            return member.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute)).FirstOrDefault() as TAttribute;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is why the two methods in the question were separate to begin with.  It's easier to write

```
var attr = someobject.GetMember(x => x.Height).GetAttribute<FooAttribute>();
```

than to write

```
var attr = someobject.GetAttribute<Foo, FooAttribute, FooProperty>(x => x.Height);
```

Comment: *Unfortunately, once you specify one generic type argument, you need to specify all three of them.* Yes this is my experience in the compiler, I hoped there was some other way. Though I prefer your second form, as it is one less unnecessary function.

Comment: enums are not "normal" types in c#.  You cannot access their properties with expressions.  You would need to write a different method for them.